# Azure AD B2C: I want to have an way to check if Email ID already exists during Account Creation, so that User can notify Account already exists

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

As a Platform Owner, I want to have an API to check if Email ID already exists during Account Creation, so that User can notify Account already exists

Scenario :

User registered using AD or Apple using a particular email ID , when he registers using gmail using the same email id , he is able to register but when is tries to login to application he receives a Profile-Api error by backend CRM.

I am looking for a way a user is notified if the particular email id is present already at the time of registration.

I am still looking for a solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

In the sign-up custom profile user journey, call a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to CRM to check if the user already exists.

If they do, use a [Paragraph](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f) to pop up an error message.

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this as `azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy` you could enforce the email uniqueness across social and local identities at the time of signing up using the Azure AD B2C directory user profile data. This would save an API call to the external CRM.

The [force-unique-email-across-social-identities](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-unique-email-across-social-identities) sample code walks through what changes you'd need to implement in your Identity Experience Framework Custom Policies.

If you're doing this on the built-in User Flows you can use [API Connectors - Before Creating the User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow#before-creating-the-user) to validate uniqueness from a backend CRM and prevent the sign-up.